# How to apply ratelimiting (restricting access) on logged-in users taking screenshots of my website?

Tags: security, screenshot, firewall, rate-limiting, ip-restrictions

I maintain a record of users' email/IP taking screenshots (44 keypress) of our website.
Currently, I am blocking them based on their weekly screenshot count.

However, I'm thinking of applying daily rate-limiting such that they are restricted access for some time (which is increased if they cross daily thresholds multiple times & the daily threshold limit also starts to decrease) and at some point, they are permanently restricted.

Is this the best way to reduce unrestrained screenshots of my website?

Thank You

I tried restricting users based on their weekly print-screen count. However, there were some users who were crossing the weekly threshold in only a few hours. I would definitely like to restrict such users immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have a hard time restricting access based on a client side action. Screenshots can always be taken by using OS tools, such as snipping tool, or web scrapers [EyeWitness](https://github.com/FortyNorthSecurity/EyeWitness). It may be worth going back to the drawing board to get some better answers:

1. Why do you want to block people for taking screenshots?
2. Is this temporary restriction going to actually stop this happening?
3. How long to you want users to be restricted for?
4. Have you researched any methods of preventing screenshots from being taken? Rather than trying to detect who takes them?
5. Have you warned users that taking screenshots will result in them being blocked? This may stop them in the first place.